# Adding small png image to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to store some small png images in Amazon DynamoDB table. There isn't a file field in the items for a table. Anyone know how to do this. I would like to store it via the web console and then read it from an iOS app. I just can't see any way of uploading a file to the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to do that via the console. You could store the png as binary data in the table, but honestly that probably is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

The common pattern for associating files with a DynamoDB record is to store the file in S3 and store the key or URL of that file in DynamoDB.